# Create 2 way map for sha256.

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, sha256

Assuming we are looking at the data set of all sha256.
Each sha256 value whan aplying the sha256 function on it will result in a different sha256 value. 
Since our data set is in the same size as the result set we can assume we have a 1 to 1 function.

Is there a way to map all the value and create a backwared function. (Assuming we are looking only on the above data set.

In a reseanable computational time (not 110 years)

Comment: "*Since our data set is in the same size as the result set we can assume we have a 1 to 1 function.*" Faulty reasoning. You're talking about two different result sets.

Comment: Why? I am looking on all the sha256 value as the src, and all the sha256 value as the dest.

Comment: All the sha256 values of what input set?

Comment: [a-f0-9]{64} data set as src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since our data set is in the same size as the result set we can assume we have a 1 to 1 function.

This is a faulty assumption. There is no reason to believe that SHA256 is a unique mapping across 256-bit inputs; there is, in all probability, at least one (and probably many) pairs of 256-inputs which have the same SHA256 hash.

> Is there a way to map all the value and create a backwared function.

No. There are 2<sup>256</sup> ≈ 1.16×10<sup>77</sup> possible SHA256 hashes. As a point of comparison, [there are roughly 2.4×10<sup>67</sup> atoms in our galaxy](https://educationblog.oup.com/secondary/maths/numbers-of-atoms-in-the-universe). Even if you could turn the entire Milky Way into a computer and write one hash onto each atom, you would run out of atoms long before you finished.